# Dump CCWs and RCWs in a mixed managed/unmanaged process

Tags: .net, interop, windbg, com-interop, mixed-mode

I have a mixed managed/unmanaged environment (Visual Studio and ReSharper) and I suspect CCW or RCW leak. Is there any way to dump all currently allocated wrappers and identify their source/target? I have WinDbg, SOS & SOSEx, so I can see total number of RCWs and CCWs with !syncblk command. I just want to see objects, so I can call !gcroot on them and otherwise examine suspects.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `!dumpheap` to do this.  `!dumpheap -stat` would let you find the type names (if you don't already know them) and then `!dumpheap -type {typename}` would give you the individual object addresses which can be passed to `!gcroot`.

Comment: I do know how to use !dumpheap, I was asking about CCW & RCW, not about all managed objects. How would I distinguish CCW or RCW from other objects in the dumpheap output?

Comment: Use their type names.  It's been a long time since I used these, but you should be able to use their type names to restrict the output from !dumpheap by using the -type option -- which also supports wild cards.  If you're not sure what their type names are, use -stat to list all types.

Comment: @Curt, CCWs are not represented as managed object. All RCWs has type of __ComObject.

Comment: Ilya, not all RCW has __ComObject in the name. They may have a "normal" name, if some interop assembly is used (created by VS.Net when you reference the COM object).